# How can I use the “Xamarin.Forms.Contacts 1.0.3” Plugin to create a list view of the contacts?

Tags: c#, plugins, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, contacts

I have been researching a plugin that allows me to access the contacts in the phone of the user to display them in a list view. I tried to use James Montemagno “ContactsPlugin” but it is no longer supported. So, I found a plugin called “Xamarin.Forms.Contacts 1.0.3” which claims to be able to access the contacts but I don't know how to activate the plugin for it to display the contacts. Does anyone know how to use this plugin or knows how to access the contacts using something else? I am currently using the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 for Mac.

Plugin link: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Contacts/

Comment: the Github page contains sample code and the list of permissions required.  Have you tried that?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: What don't you understand how to do?  It is 4 lines of instructions posted at the top of the nuget page.

Comment: Okey, already turned on the permissions but I don't understand how to activate the plugin. How can I use this code snippet " var contacts = await Plugin.ContactService.CrossContactService.Current.GetContactListAsync();"

Comment: based on the docs I'd guess that you don't need to do anything to activate it.  Just call GetContactListAsync() when you want to retrieve the contacts.

Comment: Also,  how can I display them in a list view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a sample app in the GitHub repo that demonstrates exactly what you want

```
var contacts = await Plugin.ContactService.CrossContactService.Current.GetContactListAsync();

lstContacts.ItemsSource = contacts;

  <ListView 
    x:Name="lstContacts"
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Email}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: I was able to build and run the app but nothing appears. The app displays a white screen and no information. What can I do?

Comment: use the debugger

Comment: I already ran the app on Android (Android_Accelerated_Nougat (API 25) ) with debug and ad-hoc and neather displayed any information.